# Concerning the defnition of a sufficient statistic

Tags: real-analysis, probability, statistics

I was wondering if anybody could help me here. I do not have access to a mathematical professor, and learn everything on my own. My question deals with the interpretation/definition of a sufficient statistic. I often see people saying things like "in terms of estimation, having the sufficient statistic is just as good as having the entire sample."

Fine, but what is referred to here when we say estimation? Is this always in terms of maximum liklihood estimation? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, UMVUE is also a function of the minimal sufficient statistic. MLE is always a function of the minimal sufficient statistic. Basically, I would dare to say that any good estimator (excluding some pathological cases) will be a function of he minimal sufficient statistic.

Comment: Thank zou for your answer. What type of estimation is then meant when it is said that

" having the sufficient statistic is just as good as having the entire sample" ?

Comment: Estimation of parameters in parametric models. Maybe no special method is considered, rather a general statement on estimation

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I understand the intuition now. One last thing: Say theta is our parameter of interest, and f(X) is our sufficient statistic. If the definition is 
P(x | f, theta) does not depend on theta, 

does this IMPLY that 

P(theta | f, x) = P(theta | f) 

so that when evaluating the probability of theta, we can discard x after having seen f?

Comment: Basically, yes, as the (Fisher) information of $f$ equals to info. in $X_1,..,X_n$

Comment: Do you know of a formal discussion of this equivalence?

Comment: You can start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information#Sufficient_statistic